# Window before nested emits

Tags: rxjs

I have observable `[1,1,1,2,2,1,1]`, and want to convert it in observable of sums of same elements group, so result would be `[3,4,2]`. I wrote this code:

```js
from([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1])
  .pipe(
    connect((numbers$) =>
      numbers$.pipe(window(checkChange(numbers$)), mergeMap(sumNumbers))
    )
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);

function checkChange(obs$: Observable<number>): Observable<any> {
  return obs$.pipe(
    pairwise(),
    filter(([a, b]) => a !== b),
    map(() => "change")
  );
}

function sumNumbers(obs$: Observable<number>): Observable<number> {
  return obs$.pipe(reduce((acc, n) => acc + n, 0));
}
```

But it returns observable `[5,3,1]`. This is because original observable windows after element where change happens, and not before. So it groups by `[[1,1,1,2],[2,1],[1]]`, and not `[[1,1,1],[2,2],[1,1]]`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve it using other `notifier` observable that runs before the window observable gets processed.

You could do something like this

```
const source = from([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]);
const myNotifier = new Subject<number>(); //Subject to be used as notifier

source
  .pipe(
    connect((shared$) =>
      merge(
        shared$.pipe(notifyOnChange(myNotifier)), // 1st run the notifier stream
        shared$.pipe(window(myNotifier)) // 2nd the windowed one.
      )
    ),
    mergeMap(sumNumbers)
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);

function notifyOnChange<T>(notifier: Subject<T>) {
  return (obs$: Observable<T>): Observable<never> =>
    obs$.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(), // only lets through the value if different to previous one
      skip(1), // skip the first emission
      tap(notifier), // notify the change
      ignoreElements() //prevent the next notification propagation
    );
}

function sumNumbers(obs$: Observable<number>): Observable<number> {
  return obs$.pipe(reduce((acc, n) => acc + n, 0));
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`reduce`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/reduce) instead to maintain the current value being counted, running count of correct value, and an array of previous counts.

```js
import {from} from 'rxjs';
import {reduce,map} from 'rxjsoperators';

from([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]).pipe(
  reduce(
    ({ prevCounts, prev, count }, cur) => (count === undefined) ? {
      prevCounts,
      prev : cur,
      count : 1
    } : (prev === cur) ? {
      prevCounts,
      prev,
      count: count + 1
    } : {
      prevCounts: [...prevCounts, count],
      prev: cur,
      count: 1
    },
    { prevCounts : [] }
  ),
  // append count to prevCounts array
  map(({ prevCounts, count }) => (count) ?  [...prevCounts, count] : prevCounts)
).subscribe({
  next: x => console.log(x)
});
```

This code doesn't use array.push because that changes the array in place and while in this case it wouldn't be a bad thing I've learned it's safer to have the functional programming habit of either returning *unchanged* objects or *new* objects.